# assign min values based on iloc and its range from another two column

Tags: pandas

**df**

```
            A  idx1 idx2
2022/1/1    0   2   4
2022/1/2    1   1   3
2022/1/3    2   0   3
2022/1/4    3   3   4
2022/1/5    4   0   4
```

**expected df**

```
            A idx1 idx2 lowest
2022/1/1    0   2   4   2
2022/1/2    1   1   3   1
2022/1/3    2   0   3   0
2022/1/4    3   3   4   3
2022/1/5    4   0   4   0
```

**Goal**

Assign lowest column from A column using iloc method where start index is idx1.values and end index is idx2.values as below:

```
 df['lowest']=df.A.iloc[df.idx1.values:df.idx2.values].min()
```

But get `TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers.`

And I don't want to change original index.

And if there are million rows, the speed should be considered.So numpy method is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of is doing it the following way. Did try to time it and it was 10 times faster than normal apply:

Change values of column `A` to numpy array first. Then still use apply along axis=1 but `raw=True` which passes each row as numpy array. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for information:

> the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance.

```py
arr = df['A'].to_numpy()
df['lowest'] = df.apply(lambda row: arr[row[1]:row[2]].min(), axis=1, raw=True)
```

IIUC, You can try it like this:

```
df['lowest'] = df.apply(lambda row: df.iloc[row['idx1']:row['idx2'], 0].min(), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            A  idx1  idx2  lowest
2022-01-01  0     2     4       2
2022-01-02  1     1     3       1
2022-01-03  2     0     3       0
2022-01-04  3     3     4       3
2022-01-05  4     0     4       0
```

Comment: what's the meaning of 0? Is it referred A column?

Comment: yes. `iloc` takes only integers as arguments. But you could split it and do it with `.loc['A']`. I'm searching for a vectorized numpy way but so far no clue.